# Buffering in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, buffer, documentation

I'm looking for some examples to do simple python scripts in QGIS. How would I do a buffer analysis on a dataset?

I can't seem to find much in the manual and QGIS python that quite matches the ESRI documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the [PyQGIS Cookbook](http://www.qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/vector.html).

Follow the example on how to iterate over a vector layer. Accessing the geometry, you can apply the buffer() method. See also the QGIS API: http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometry.html#a98208752e1beb1a5d3a7eedffbfdb2e4

Answer (score 12):

You have different ways to get what you want by PyQGIS Console:

1. Aragon's suggestion;
2. by using QgsGeometryAnalyzer class:

```py
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.analysis import QgsGeometryAnalyzer 
mc = iface.mapCanvas() 
layer = mc.currentLayer()
QgsGeometryAnalyzer().buffer(layer, "path_to/output.shp", 500, False, False, -1)
```

1. by using Sextante class:

```py
from sextante.core.Sextante import Sextante
Sextante.runalg("ftools:fixeddistancebuffer","input_path.shp", False, 500, 5, True, "output_path_buffer.shp")
```

To get the sextante parameters type `Sextante.alghelp("ftools:fixeddistancebuffer")` in PyQGIS Console.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 11):

if you want basic code, you can try:

```
#Don't forget to Toggle Editing

lyr = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
provider = lyr.dataProvider()
feat= QgsFeature()
alls = provider.attributeIndexes()
provider.select(alls)

while provider.nextFeature(feat):
    buff = feat.geometry().buffer(5,2)
    lyr.dataProvider().changeGeometryValues({feat.id(): buff})
```

Comment: Thanks - is QgsFeature the layer name or should it include an absolute path? And buffer(5,2) is that distance?

Comment: you can also do this with a for loop and you also can avoid selecting the attributes if not needed https://gist.github.com/4094707

Comment: @GISDanny QgsFeature is a container class for the a feature e.g. attribute and geometry in QGIS.  The layer is the qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer() bit, that will use the currently active layer in QGIS.

Comment: Is it possible to specify units when buffering in Python? I keep trying to buffer a point layer I believe I have set to a CRS with units in feet but the buffers I am getting are huge- the point layer was originally imported from csv with lat long cords but when I created a vector layer out of it I specified a local system. Something is obviously wrong.

Answer (score 9):

Just a little thing to add to the last reply.

To search for a SEXTANTE algorithm about a given topic, use Sextante.alglist(). For instance, in the case of searching for something containing "buffer", you would do

```
>>> from sextante.core.Sextante import Sextante
>>> Sextante.alglist("buffer")
```

And you would get:

```
Grid Buffer------------------------------------------>saga:gridbuffer
Grid Proximity Buffer-------------------------------->saga:gridproximitybuffer
Shapes Buffer---------------------------------------->saga:shapesbuffer
Threshold Buffer------------------------------------->saga:thresholdbuffer
Fixed distance buffer-------------------------------->ftools:fixeddistancebuffer
Variable distance buffer----------------------------->ftools:variabledistancebuffer
r.buffer - Creates a raster map layer showing buffer zones surrounding cells that contain non-NULL category values.--->grass:r.buffer
v.buffer.angle--------------------------------------->grass:v.buffer.angl
v.buffer.column - Creates a buffer around features of given type.--->grass:v.buffer.column
v.buffer.distance - Creates a buffer around features of given type.--->grass:v.buffer.distance
v.buffer.minordistance------------------------------->grass:v.buffer.minordistance
```

That way, you can find the name of the algorithm to call (ftools:fixeddistancebuffer, in the example proposed in the reply above)

You can turn your script into a new algorithm in SEXTANTE. The SEXTANTE documentation has detailed information about that.

Comment: That a great tip worth mentioning on your sextante blog. I was looking for this yesterday.