# Calculate number of people within 50 km of a point

Tags: qgis, geoprocessing

I have two data sets:

- World population (raster) in EPSG:4326, from http://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/data/set/gpw-v3-population-density-future-estimates/data-download
- A shapefile with points (distributed around the globe), also in  EPSG:4326

I would like to calculate the number of people within for example 50 km from each point. What would be the best way of doing this in QGIS?

Comment: I recommend reading about PostGIS (SQL) and R, might come handy if you need do more spatial analysis in future

Comment: ST_Contains http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/ST_Contains.html source: http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/reference.html#Spatial_Relationships_Measurements

Comment: perhaps an answer to overlapping buffers could be to store the non-buffered area as a shape and subtract the population in the non-buffer area from the total

Answer (score 1):

Use Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Buffer on your point shapefile to create a 50km radius circle around each point.

Use the Zonal Stats plugin (its a core plugin, but must be activated in Manage Plugins) to calculate the sum (among other stats) of the raster cells inside of each polygon of the resulting shapefile.

Comment: This only works provided no two points are closer than 50 km: when the buffers overlap, zonal stats will not be able to obtain the correct answer.  Instead, compute a focal sum (with a 50 km radius circular neighborhood) and extract its values at each of the points in the shapefile.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Two questions:

- Since the data is in lat/long and I will use meters for the analysis, I will have to reproject the data to suitable coordinate system. Any suggestions on which one to use for a global data set?

- The buffer zones will probably overlap. Can you tell me a bit more about how to compute a focal sum?

Magnus

Comment: @whuber, I have never noticed problems using QGIS Zonal Stats  plugin with overlaping polygons, but I know that it's a Problem in ArcGIS (9.3). I made a small test, using two polygons with the same shape\size, and overlap them. Using the QGIS plugin and the resulting count, sum and mean for each polygon was the expected.

Comment: Very interesting!  That's nice to know, and I am pleased to have been wrong about QGIS in this regard.  Based on what you say, it sounds like the zonal stats solution should be preferred unless there are a very many points with very many overlaps, in which case the focal stats solution--with its much greater computational efficiency--may have some merit as an option.

Comment: Johnrobot, your query about a suitable global projection needs some careful thought. I would like to suggest you review [similar questions on this site](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2Bglobal+%2Bdistance) and then, if they do not indicate a solution, post that as a separate question. It looks like you could [compute a variable distance buffer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41267/how-to-buffer-in-pyqgis/41356#41356) in a conformal projection, [varying the radii](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14750/global-dem-to-slope-calculation/40464#40464) with the scale.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I have had a go using http://www.gistutor.com/postgresqlpostgis/6-advanced-postgresqlpostgis-tutorials/58-postgis-buffer-latlong-and-other-projections-using-meters-units-custom-stbuffermeters-function.html, perhaps that will be of use to someone else, too.