# How to find reasonable locations (location study)?

Tags: qgis, geoprocessing, buffer

My GIS skills got a little rusty and I am new in using QGIS (I have learned on ARC).

I have created a map with population estimates and points. I created a buffer around the points of 75km and calculated the population within the buffers (There are overlaps that are not elegant, as they are multiple-counted but thats not my priority). I basically followed this introduction: [Calculate number of people within 50 km of a point](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49203/calculate-number-of-people-within-50-km-of-a-point)

Is there a way to calculate potential areas (in this case within europe), where my buffers miss out on largely populated areas?

Basically I would like to receive 75 km buffers located at those areas.

Comment: What form are the population estimates in? Is that a raster?

Comment: It is a vector with populatiom estimates

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/tag/world-file/) library data.
Download the two layers of [populated places](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/110m-cultural-vectors) in 1:110m scale, in order if having as much data as possible for your project.

The "populated places"  layer will give you a polygon layer with the largest populated area, but it neglect the smallest places [image]
The "simple" map will give you a points for that marks the populated areas [image]
It is important to note that this layer are for the all world and just for Europe [image]
In order of working just on Europe you need a polygon layer of Europe, so you will be able to define and work only on your area of interest.  You can find this kind of layer in the [GeoTECH](http://techcenter.jefferson.kctcs.edu/data/) Data Library.

Comment: Great!, can you mark it as anserd?