# How to create multiple buffers based on a list of values?

Tags: qgis, buffer, attribute-driven

I am looking for a method to buffer geometries by passing a list of buffer amount values in QGIS. The resulting polygon layers should be suffixed with the buffer amount by some way. By passing i.e. (10,13,15) I would expect the following result (drawn with inkscape):

[image]

What I have tried so far:

- None of the tools available in QGIS (menu-bar and geoprocessing) accept input of such list.
- The 'Multi Ring Buffer' plugin only computes equidistant buffers.
- The following script does work so far, but `QgsGeometryAnalyser.buffer()` seems to lack a parameter for how many segments to approximate (thus, I'm getting nice 20-hedrons when buffering a point)

  ```
  radiouses = [10.0, 13.0, 15.0]
  for r in radiouses:
      shapeout = 'c:\\temp\\point_buf_%s' % r
      QgsGeometryAnalyser.buffer(iface.mapCanvas.currentLayer(), shapeout, r, False, False, -1)
  ```

Comment: Without knowing how your buffer column is laid out it's a little tricky but having a quick look GRASS might be a good option. Have a look at "v.buffer.column".  If you us this tool inside QGIS graphical modeler you'll be able to automate the whole thing and give each output it's own title.  Little long winded but it might work

Comment: You can try to use Sextante (see [this answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/41342/64955)) instead of QgsGeometryAnalyser. It has a "segment" argument which might be useful.

Comment: The Multi-distance buffer QGIS Plugin allows the specification of a set of buffer distances, so if manual input is an option, that plugin should solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `QgsGeometryAnalyser`, you could try calling the Processing function:

```
import processing
radiouses = [10.0, 13.0, 15.0]
for r in radouses:
    shapeout = 'c:\\temp\\point_buf_%s' % r
processing.runalg("qgis:fixeddistancebuffer", iface.activeLayer(), r, 99, False, shapeout )
```