# Creating temporary buffer layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, buffer

I have been able to select features using an attribute from a Point vector file:

```
expr = QgsExpression("\"NAME\" = 'PESCOE'") 
collegePoint = collegeLayer.getFeatures( QgsFeatureRequest (expr))

#get ids  
ids = [i.id() for i in collegePoint]

#select the features  
collegeLayer.setSelectedFeatures(ids)
```

Now for each of the selected features I wish to create a temporary buffer layer (not as presented in [Buffering in pyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41267/buffering-in-pyqgis), as it is not quite clear).

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the following which:

1. Creates a list of your selected features.
2. Clears the selection.
3. Iterates through each feature in the list, selects it and runs the processing buffer algorithm.
4. Each buffer is a temporary output which are immediately loaded.

Note that the **"Use only selected features"** option must be enabled in:

```
Processing > Options > General > Use only selected features
```

Here is the code:

```
import processing
layer = iface.activeLayer()
feat_list = []
for feat in layer.selectedFeatures():
    feat_list.append(feat)

layer.removeSelection()

for selected_feat in feat_list:
    layer.select( selected_feat.id() )
    processing.runandload("qgis:fixeddistancebuffer", layer, 0.01, 99, False, None)
    layer.removeSelection()
```

---

Example:

Sample points:

[image: Sample points]

Result:

[image: Results]

Comment: what if i want all the buffers in one layer and not a separate layer for each buffer ?

Comment: @AbhijitGujar - Just run `processing.runandload("qgis:fixeddistancebuffer", layer, 0.01, 99, False, None)` without a `for` loop :)

Comment: Thanks but what i want is to make buffer for 1000 features but i certainly don't want 1000 buffers in layer panel but i need all 1000 buffers in one layer

Comment: @AbhijitGujar - Could you ask this as a [new question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) please? I'm not sure I follow. Also include any code you have used :)