# Conduct Buffer Analysis in PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, anaconda

- Given that I have 1 shapefiles for instance `c:/users/user/line.shp`
- and I have activated my QGIS Console in Anaconda prompt

```
(base) $ conda activate qgis-venv
(qgis-venv) $ python

>>> import qgis
>>> #????
```

- How should I put command in the console to execute buffer of 500?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this :

```py
import sys
from qgis.core import (
     QgsApplication, 
     QgsProcessingFeedback, 
     QgsVectorLayer
)

# See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/155852/4972 for details about the prefix 
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath('/usr', True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()

# Append the path where processing plugin can be found
sys.path.append('/docs/dev/qgis/build/output/python/plugins')

import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()

vlayer = QgsVectorLayer('P:/Test/qgis_test/poly_test.shp', "poly_test", "ogr")

parameter_dictionary = {
    'INPUT' : vlayer,
    'DISTANCE' : 500,
    'SEGMENTS' : 25,
    'END_CAP_STYLE' : 0,
    'JOIN_STYLE' : 1,
    'MITER_LIMIT' : 10,
    'DISSOLVE' : False,
    'OUTPUT' : 'memory:'
    }

buffer_result = processing.run("native:buffer", parameter_dictionary)

output = buffer_result['OUTPUT']
```

Also do not forget to check the [QGIS Documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing/console.html#calling-algorithms-from-the-python-console)

---

**References:**

- [Using QGIS 3 Processing algorithms from PyQGIS standalone scripts (outside of GUI)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/279874/using-qgis-3-processing-algorithms-from-pyqgis-standalone-scripts-outside-of-gu)
- [Buffering in PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41267/buffering-in-pyqgis)

Comment: this works! thank you.